# Merging audio wav files together

Tags: python, audio, wav

I want to merge two audio files (wav format) together, but can't seem to get it right.

```
def wav_2x():
  for _ in range(2):
    print(files[np.random.randint(20000)])
```

When run, I get, for example:

```
/content/drive/MyDrive/Data/MLEnd/training/Training/0006606.wav
/content/drive/MyDrive/Data/MLEnd/training/Training/0007514.wav
```

Is there a way I can merge these two together into one audio file?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try **pydub**.

Install

```
pip3 install pydub
```

Example

```
# pydub example
from pydub import AudioSegment
audio_one = AudioSegment.from_file("0006606.wav")
audio_two = AudioSegment.from_file("0007514.wav")
merged = audio_one + audio_two
```

Original Example: http://pydub.com/

pypi: https://pypi.org/project/pydub/